# Roaming domain profiles in a mixed windows 8 and 7 enviroment

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, windows-domain

How will things work when a user's roaming profile from windows 7 machines have to be used on windows 8 machines? Or actually the other way around.

Will this force windows 8 migration just to keep roaming profiles consistent?
Any suggestions on things to avoid problems would be appreciated.

Comment: I actually hadn't tried yet, but I know there will be new machines with windows 8 to deal with coming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's worth being concerned about, or at least prepared.

Luckily there's plenty to get you started (from MS):

[Unpredictable behavior if you migrate a roaming user profile from Windows 8 to Windows 7](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2748329)

Couple blurbs from that KB article:

> Windows 7 and Windows 8 use similar user profile formats, which do not
>   support interoperability when they roam between computers that are
>   running different versions of Windows. When a user who has a Windows 7
>   profile signs in to a Windows 8-based computer for the first time, the
>   user profile is updated to the new Windows 8 format. After this
>   occurs, the user profile is no longer compatible with Windows 7-based
>   computers.

.

> When a user who has a Windows 7 roaming profile signs in to a Windows
>   8-based computer for the first time, the user's roaming profile is
>   updated to the new Windows 8 format. The Windows 8 user profile format
>   is incompatible with Windows 7-based computers.
>
> If a user must switch between Windows 7-based and Windows 8-based
>   computers, then you must configure the **Set roaming profile path for
>   all users logging onto this computer** Group Policy setting for the
>   computers.

The full KB (obviously) contains more information and how to deal with it.